# Can I combine more than one function in a single line in SQL?

Tags: sql

What I want to do is simply to use more than 1 function in a single query. I'm new to SQL so I'm sorry if I'm getting some words wrong.

`select cognom from emp where length(cognom) = 10, replace(cognom, ' ', '*');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, as long as you respect the syntax. The 'line' does not mean anything because you can write all your query in a single line, even if it's not recommended to facilitate the comprehension.
In your case, what its wrong is your `replace()` that should either be in the select part to manipulate output data, or match a where statement.
In fact, you can have as many function as you need, which could be something like this:

```sql
SELECT col1, func1(col2) as txt2, func2(col3) as text3
  FROM your_table
 WHERE col1 = 12
   AND func4(col5) = 'XYZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you require but preumably you are looking for the following

```
select replace(cognom, ' ', '*') as cognom
from emp
where length(cognom) = 10;
```